# add_executable Error - CMake

Tags: compiling, cmake

I created a package and source file in my Ubuntu 20.04 computer. My goal is to visualize dummy sensors and objects in Rviz2. To do that I followed the  [How to visualize sensor data in ROS2](https://s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/readme.theconstructsim.com/chris.ch.v@gmail.com/how_to_visualize_sensor_data_in_ros2_dashing/How_to_visualize_sensor_data_in_ROS2.html) article. And, when I went to build the package with the command:

```
colcon build --symlink-install
```

I got this error:

[image: Error]

The `cmake` file I used is the following:

[image: C Make Fİle]

I am using ROS2 foxy distro.

Comment: This sounds like an question about `cmake` and/or programming - rather than about Ubuntu. It would probably be more appropriate on [so]

Answer (score 0):

When you have an `add_executable` command in cmake, it expects the files you list to exist relative to the location of your `CMakeLists.txt` file.  So, for example, your workspace might look something like this:

```
.
└── my_package
    ├── CMakeLists.txt
    ├── include
    │   └── my_package
    ├── package.xml
    └── src
        └── dolly_follow.cpp
```

It looks like the tutorial you're following just copy & pasted a `CMakeLists.txt` from the [dolly](https://github.com/chapulina/dolly) repository, but did not instruct you to actually pull any code from the repository; I would say the problem here is that the tutorial's instructions are unclear.

If you don't intend to actually compile a C++ file named `dolly_follow.cpp`, you can both remove the `add_executable` command that refers to it and the later `install` command that references the `add_executable` command's target.

Comment: Yes you are right. The instructions are not clear.
Thanks for your answer.